# is it bug of border-radius in Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari

In Safari, an applying a `:hover` style causes incorrect repainting. Is it bug in Safari?

[image]

- Safari version: 11.0.3 (11604.5.6.1.1)
- UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/604.5.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0.3 Safari/604.5.6

```css
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.outer {
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <a href="javascript:void 0" class="inner">hello</a>
</div>
```

***jsfiddle***: https://jsfiddle.net/z71z5jov/

Comment: I'm using your same version an it look good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug and I believe it to be big enough so that they will notice shortly, but nevertheless, you might want to open an issue on their [issue tracker](https://bugs.webkit.org) <sub>if no dupe has been opened yet</sub>.

Just a note before the hacks: this not only happens when hovered, [even triggering the repaint by js](https://jsfiddle.net/z71z5jov/2/) does reproduce the issue, and not only on `<a>` elements either and even weirder, it fixes by itself after some time.

So now, the hackish workaround:

Setting a transparent `border` on your inner element seems to prevent the bug...

```css
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.outer {
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  border: solid 1px transparent; /* Safari workaround */
  margin: -1px; /* counter-act the workaround */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <a href="javascript:void 0" class="inner">hello</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe related: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=69091 and probably related: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=140535